# how to protect certain range if cell equals some value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking a way to "conditionally protect" some of my sheet's ranges. I know it's not possible without a script... So I would need this:
On open, protect range (A6:A) from being modified if A2="C". Else if, leave unprotected.
This should be repeated on open in 10 sheets with given names (Com1, Com2,...,Com10)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried writing any code for this?

Comment: Welcome There is a Help topic called [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Would you re-read this topic and then edit your question to supply more information about your scenario, about the work that that you have already done (successful or not), and any other relevant information that will assist people answering the question. Would you please also share your spreadsheet (though you should remove confidential or private information).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Apps Script reference to [access and modify protected ranges in sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection). You can build a Protection object which contains permissions for who can edit a given range.

Google Sheets has simple triggers including a function that will run [`onOpen()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onopene) which you can put your code inside. The full [Apps Script reference for extending Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) provides a great resource for building functions to edit and manipulate structures and data of Spreadsheets.

You'll want to use [`.getRange('A6:A')`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/banding#getRange()) and build a condition which calls the [`.protect()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect) method if `A2 = 'C'`.

You can also you use [`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheets()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) to get all the sheets from the spreadsheet and iterate through the returned array using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to apply your protection to all sheets.